# Customize query of postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I am using postgresql database, for i am trying to achieve like i have two queries and but i don't want to use multiple queries so is it possible to manage by single query ?

Query 1 :

```
select coalesce(sum("dummy"),0) as sum from generate_series ('2014-09-09 00:00:00'::timestamp,'2014-09-09 23:59:59','1 minute')
minutes(minute) LEFT JOIN report ON 
minutes.minute=date_trunc('minute', report.fetchdate)
AND fetchdate >= '2014-09-09 00:00:00' AND fetchdate <= '2014-09-09 23:59:00'
AND  entity_id ='0' group by minute order by minute
```

OUTPUT:

Total count of dummy field for each minutes of  each day it means each day have total (24*60=1440) records

Note : This Query Using for single Day

Query2 :

```
select date(day)as day,coalesce(sum("dummy"),0) as sum from generate_series ('2014-09-06 00:00:01'::date,'2014-09-12 23:59:59'::date,'1 day'::interval) days(day) LEFT JOIN report ON days.day=date_trunc('day', report.fetchdate) AND  entity_id ='0' group by day order by day
```

OUTPUT:

```
give total count of dummy field  for each day between day 2014-09-06 to 2014-09-12 it means total 7 records (Date : 6,7,8,9,10,11,12)
```

Note :This Query using for more than 1 days

Required Output:

1) Need to see total count of dummy field of each day between specified date(Output of 2nd query)

2) Need to see maximum call of each day

Ex :
Suppose i am search by any two days  then need to break in single date and get data for each minute of each date and whenever we have maximum count of dummy field of particular day then need to show as output maximum call for each day

Comment: _Need to see maximum call of each day_ You mean maximum `sum("dummy")` grouped by minute?

Comment: @Clodoaldo Neto Exactly you are right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select
    date_trunc('day', minute) as day,
    sum(minute_sum) as day_sum,
    max(minute_sum) as max_minute_sum
from (
    select
        minute,
        coalesce(sum("dummy"),0) as minute_sum
    from
        generate_series(
            '2014-09-06'::timestamp,
            '2014-09-13'::timestamp - interval '1 minute',
            '1 minute'
        ) minutes(minute)
        left join
        report on
            minutes.minute = date_trunc('minute', report.fetchdate)
            and entity_id ='0'
    group by minute
) s
group by 1
order by 1
```

Comment: above query it doesn't show sum and max for last date i mean for 2014-09-13 else its working fine please help me if you can

Comment: @Ankit: In your sample the last date was 2014-09-12 hence my query only shows that. If you want to include the 13th then set the last date to 2014-09-14